# Hibernate Criteria Join latest status and filter result

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a table of Orders, and a table of Order Status Updates that points to order.id. I need to get a list of Orders, but I need to join in order status updates because I don't want orders which last status is 'Cancelled'

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`end_customer_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `FK_end_customer` (`end_customer_id`),
CONSTRAINT `orders_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`end_customer_id`) REFERENCES `end_customers` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=100333 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `order_status_updates` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `order_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_order` (`order_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `order_status_updates_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=344180 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Current Criteria is:

```
final Criteria c = criteria("o")
    .add(eq("o.endCustomer.id", endCustomerId));
return list(c.addOrder(desc("createdAt")));
```

I need to filter out Orders which latest status (sorted by Date) is Cancelled

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a class called `MyOrder` and an `ORDER_STATUS` enum as well as `id`, `status` and `createdAt` field definitions:

```
final Criteria c = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(MyOrder.class);

c.add(Restrictions.eq("id", yourId))
 .add(Restrictions.ne("status", ORDER_STATUS.CANCELLED)
 .addOrder(Order.desc("createdAt"));
```

Comment: Not applicable to the question, status is not a column in Order. It's a separated table...